# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I use the Nuget manager for updating jQuery:

> Install-Package jQuery

The following error occurs:

> jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

But jQuery updates succesfully .

```
Successfully installed 'jQuery 2.2.3'.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax 2.0.20710.0' from IIT_WEB_APP.
You are downloading Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/mvc_4_eula_enu.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax 2.0.30506.0'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax 2.0.30506.0' to IIT_WEB_APP.
The intellisense file was not found in project at path D:\AAAAAAAAAAAA From Rezon\IIT_NEW_Stable_26-05-16_2\IIT_NEW\IIT_WEB_APP\Scripts\jquery-1.7.1.intellisense.js
Successfully removed 'jQuery 1.7.1.1' from IIT_WEB_APP.
Successfully added 'jQuery 2.2.3' to IIT_WEB_APP.
IntelliSense JS files are not supported by your version of Visual Studio: 10
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax 2.0.20710.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'jQuery 1.7.1.1'.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you already have some other version of jquery installed ?

Comment: May be try installing some specific version Eg. install-package jquery -version 1.9.0

Comment: @AjinderSingh yes  'jQuery 1.7.1.1'. but Successfully uninstalled 'jQuery 1.7.1.1'.

Answer (score 1):

The Masked Input Plugin only supports jQuery up to version 1.9:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ (see Changelog)